File upload into ClassPathResource - IOException
i want to upload images added by admin(add category) into folder in project directory but i try to do so with the help of controller  but it throws Unhandled exception type IOException
@PostMapping("/saveCategory")
    public String saveCategory(@ModelAttribute Category category, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
            HttpSession session) {
        System.out.println(file.getOriginalFilename());
        String imageName = file != null ? file.getOriginalFilename() : "default.jpg";
        category.setImageName(imageName);

        Boolean existCategory = categoryService.existCategory(category.getName());
        if (existCategory) {
            session.setAttribute("errorMsg", "Category name already exist");
        } else {
            Category saveCategory = categoryService.saveCategory(category);
            if (!ObjectUtils.isEmpty(saveCategory)) {
                session.setAttribute("errorMsg", "Not saved ! internally server error");
            } else {

                // first of all get the path onto which u want to upload the file.

    File saveFile = new ClassPathResource("static/img").getFile();

    Path path = Paths.get(saveFile.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "category_img" + File.separator+ file.getOriginalFilename());

                // System.out.println(path);
Files.copy(file.getInputStream(), path, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

                session.setAttribute("succMsg", "Saved successfully");

            }
        }

        return "redirect:/admin/Category";
    }


You cannot upload to the classpath. How would you add a file inside a jar file (which is what would happen when the application would be build and packaged).

You can't write to ClasspPathResource.
Replace
File saveFile = new ClassPathResource("static/img").getFile();

Path path = Paths.get(saveFile.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "category_img" + File.separator+ file.getOriginalFilename());

With
Path path = Paths.get("fullpath/to/folder" + File.separator + "category_img" + File.separator+ file.getOriginalFilename());

You should probably put "fullpath/to/folder" as a configured value and it must be reachable from the server that the java runs on.

it help me a lot thankyou so much
